# AngularJS Bootstrap/Compilation Processing Order

Tags: angularjs

Is anyone know what is the order of the angularjs processing ? Which one is initiated first ?

- directives
- controller
- filter
- module
- $rootScope / scope object
- factory/service/provider -> do they initiated before the service is used ? or just when it is used ?

Also within directive, what is the sequence between link, controller, scope, template & compile ?

Thanks all for the help.

Comment: is the order of internal processing going to change the way that you use the framework? or cause bugs in your code?

Comment: i just want to understand how it all initiated same as asp .net page life cycle.

Comment: @kwan245, this honestly doesn't warrant a question. Create each one and `console.log` a message. It's not clear to me also what "initiated" means - for example, a service is first registered, then can be configured and then instantiated.

Comment: @NewDev i am hoping to find something like https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @kwan245, SO is hardly the place for it... See if this helps: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module, but again - try it yourself with logging